# login automatically with Grails Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

My Grails app is using the Spring Security plugin. I need to login a user programatically, and I don't have access to their password. I tried the following, which supposedly worked when using the Acegi plugin (an ancestor of the Spring Security plugin):

```
// automatically login a user and assign them the USER role. 
// In my app, the email address is also the username
GrantedAuthority[] auths = [new GrantedAuthorityImpl('USER')]
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication 
        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, 'unknown', auths)
```

It seems like this has almost worked, because if I call `springSecurityService.principal` after executing the above, I get back the email address of the automatically logged in user. However, if I call `springSecurityService.currentUser` I get an error. The root cause of this error is that:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName
```

returns "Person" which is not the name of my user class. The various tags such as `<sec:loggedInUser>` also don't work, presumably for the same reason.

I wonder if this problem is somehow related to the fact that I'm using [pre-existing domain classes for user and role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899566/use-existing-domain-classes-with-spring-security-plugin) (rather than classes generated by the plugin)? If the user logs in by entering their username and password into the form (rather than programatically), everything seems to work fine.

### Update

Following [Burt's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114195/login-automatically-with-grails-spring-security/7114444#7114444), I replaced the code above with:

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(email)
```

But I still get an error on these lines within `SpringSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`

```
String className = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName
grailsApplication.getClassForName(className).get(principal.id)
```

Because `className` is set to "Person", rather than the name of my User class.

Comment: stupid question from my site: have you configured the plugin to use your custom user class? e.g. by adding
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'package.your.User'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'package.your.UserRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'package.your.Role' to your Config.groovy

Comment: No, I was told (by the plugin author) that this is not necessary in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899566/use-existing-domain-classes-with-spring-security-plugin Might be worth a try nonetheless

Comment: The `grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName` config attribute is used by the plugin's `UserDetailsService` but when you have a custom implementation you don't need to set it, you just use the real domain class name. `reauthenticate()` calls `userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)` so it should work the same way as when you're authenticating via the login page.

Comment: @Burt - did you mean I should call `reauthenticate()` after the code I originally posted or instead of? I chose the latter.

Comment: No, I mean that since authentication works with the configured UserDetailsService and reauthenticate() calls that, it should also work. The unset property shouldn't come into play.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the user exists in the database use `springSecurityService.reauthenticate()` - see [this link](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService) for Grails 2 or [this link](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#springSecurityService) for Grails 3.

This method is designed to update the authentication when a user change has made it out of sync with the database, but it's also useful for this scenario where you want to force a valid authentication for an existing user but don't know the password.

Comment: For Don's situation, this is a way better answer than mine. :)

Comment: The old 1.x link is at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService and the new 2.x link is at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService

Comment: They have moved again: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService

Comment: The docs for the grails 3 plugin is here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#springSecurityService

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code snippit from a webapp I wrote will help.  We had to auth users using a RESTful API and they provided a username and an API key..The key piece in this code is setting the authorities and the authenticated boolean.

```
class CustomAppTokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  def userDetailsService

  Authentication authenticate(Authentication customAuth) {
    def userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(customAuth.principal)
    def user = User.get(userDetails.id)
    if (user?.apiKey.equals(customAuth.credentials)) {
      customAuth.authorities = userDetails.authorities
      customAuth.authenticated = true
      return customAuth
    } else {
      return customAuth
    }
  }

  boolean supports(Class authentication) {
    return CustomAppTokenAuthentication.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
  }
}
```

And here is code from the filter that intercepts the API calls to handle the authentication

```
    def userId = request.getHeader("x-user-external-id")
    def apiKey = request.getHeader("x-user-api-key")
    if (userId && apiKey) {
      def user = User.findByExternalId(userId)

      def myAuth = new CustomAppTokenAuthentication(
              name: userId,
              credentials: apiKey,
              principal: user.username,
              authenticated: false
      )

      def auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(myAuth);
      if (auth?.authorities?.size() >= 0) {
        log.info "Successfully Authenticated ${userId} in object ${auth}"
        // Store to SecurityContextHolder
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myAuth);
      } else {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reauthenticate()` method has two limitations:

- It don't check password
- It don't fire events. That's why a lot of plugins that listen events may not work. For example the brute force defender plugin.