# automatically sign in user using springSecurityService

Tags: grails, groovy

I've tried to sign in user with `springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username)` but `springSecurityService.currentUser` is null anyway

How to trigger a sign in with username and password and also get result on `springSecurityService.currentUser`?

Answer (score 1):

`springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username)` should set `springSecurityService.currentUser` at once - at least it does in my application (I'm using spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 and Grails 2.4.4).

Please check if you are passing in an existing username, it looks as though the user cannot be found. Try something along the lines of `println User.findByUsername(username)` before trying to `reauthenticate` to debug whether the user can actually be found.

Also check that you are not hitting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129899/springsecurityservice-reauthenticate-doesnt-work-if-there-are-no-previous-jsess) problem.