# How do I customize the credentials check in the Grails Spring Security Core plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm currently creating a new application that requires users to login. I want to use the Spring Security Core plugin for this, but the only problem is that the credentials of the users are stored in a centralized system, and not locally in the database. This system can only be accessed by an API, and will tell me whether the credentials are correct or not.
Is there any way to override the credentials check of the Spring Security Code plugin, so I can check the credentials myself? Or in case this is not possible, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs on what your system looks like.

You can write your own Authentication Provider. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799431/grails-custom-authentication-provider) is answer.

You can create your own User class with datasource set on your centralized system database.

Or you can use [Spring Security CAS Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-cas)